# CreateElement then Removelement

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function that creates image when html button clicked and if click again on button it deletes created image instead. it doesn't delete when I click again on button .
any help would be appreciated.

```
 a = 0;

 function createimg() {
   var newElement = document.createElement("img");
   newElement.setAttribute("id", "img");
   newElement.setAttribute("src", "shield.png");
   var list = document.getElementById("img");
   if (a == 0) {
     document.body.appendChild(newElement);
     a = 1;
   } else
     document.body.removeChild(newElement);
 }
```

Comment: `newElement` would always refer to the newly created element. Instead you could do the element creation on `if` condition and delete it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you remove the element, remove 'list' 
not 'newElement'

try this

```
a=0;
function createimg() {
  if (a==0) {
    var newElement = document.createElement("img");
    newElement.setAttribute("id","img");
    newElement.setAttribute("src","shield.png");
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
    a=1;
  } else {
    var list= document.getElementById("img");
    document.body.removeChild(list);
  }
}
```